# Bitcoin Pay-to-PubKeyHash (P2PKH) in multi-sig addresses

Tags: raw-transaction

Can we send Pay-to-PubKeyHash (P2PKH) to an address which starts from `3` . I tried to send raw transaction to one of my coinbase address which starts from 3 but it send to completely different address which starts from `1` . How can I send transaction to address which starts from `3` ?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to sent bitcoin to a [P2SH address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) (beginning with a `3`) at Coinbase.com ?  How are you constructing the transaction?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we send Pay-to-PubKeyHash (P2PKH) to an address which starts from 3

No.

> How can I send transaction to address which starts from 3 ?

Construct scriptPub as `OP_DUP OP_PUSH(bytes20) OP_EQUAL` where `bytes20` decoded from 3-address